# Angular 6 Reactive Forms - Set the selected <option> of a <select> FormControl dynamically by condition

Tags: typescript, angular6, angular-reactive-forms

I need to know how I set the selected `<option>` of a `<select>` FormControl dynamically by condition.

Let’s say we have customers with orders. There is a dropdown menu where we select a customer and depending on that customer the options for the orders dropdown menu should be set dynamically and a specific order should be selected.

Also both dropdown menus have an `<option>` “(new customer/order)” in case there is not yet a customer or an order, so if we route to that form without having a customer, this “new” option should be selected in both drop down menus. If we have a customer without orders, the “new” option should be selected in the orders dropdown menu.

This is the form.component.html:

```
<form [formGroup]="customerForm">
    <select formControlName="customers">
        <option>(new customer)</option>
        <option [ngValue]="customer" *ngFor="let customer of customers">
            {{customer.name}}
        </option>
    </select>
    <select formControlName="orders">
        <option>(new order)</option>
        <option [ngValue]="order" *ngFor="let order of filteredOrders">
            {{order.id}}
        </option>
    </select>
</form>
```

This is the form.component.ts:

```
customerForm: FormGroup;

customers: Customer[] = [
{   "id": 1,
    "name": "Meghan Castellano",
    "orderIds": [1,2] },
{   "id": 2,
    "name": "Monika Weiss",
    "orderIds": [3,4] }];

orders: Order[] = [{"id": 1},{"id": 2},{"id": 3},{"id": 4}];

filteredOrders: Order[];

constructor( private route: ActivatedRoute,
            private fb: FormBuilder) {}

ngOnInit() {
    this.customerForm = this.fb.group({
        customers: '',
        orders: '' });

    let customerId = this.route.snapshot.getParam('id');

    if (customerId == 0) {
        this.customerForm.patchValue({
            customers: "(new customer)",
            orders: "(new order)" });
    }
    else
    {
        let customer = this.customers[customerId];

        this.customerForm.patchValue({ customers: customer.name });

        if (customer.orderIds.length != 0) {
            this.filteredOrders = getCustomersOrders(customer);

        this.customerForm.patchValue({
            orders: this.filteredOrders[0].id }
        }
    }
}

getCustomersOrders(customer: Customer): Order[] {
    let orders: Order[];

    for (var id = 0; id < customer.orderIds.length; id++) {
        let orderId = customer.orderIds[id];
        let order = this.orders.find(i => i.id == orderId);
        orders.push(order); }

    return orders;
}
```

Currently I'm routing to the form and provide an id with the url. The customer dropdown menu selects the correct customer depending on the id in the url.

However, the order dropdown menu is only populated correctly, but the selection does not work. No option at all is selected.

If I replace the value in this statement:

`this.customerForm.patchValue({ orders: this.filteredOrders[0].id }`

with the `"(new order)"` string already specified in the html:

`this.customerForm.patchValue({ order: "(new order)" })`

it works. The string `"(new order)"` is selected in the orders dropdown menu. It just don't work for the filteredOrders.

What am I doing wrong here? Do I maybe need a whole different approach here?

Comment: So, i've updated the stackblitz along with the answer. Please tell if there is something unclear with the explanations.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Okay, after a couple of hours I got it. Here are my updated .html and .ts files for your interest:

HTML:

```
<form class="form-container" [formGroup]="customerForm">
    <select formControlName="customer" (change)="onCustomerChanged($event)">
        <option>(new customer)</option>
        <option *ngFor="let customer of customers" [value]="customer.name">
            {{customer.name}}
        </option>
    </select>
    <select formControlName="order">
        <option>(new order)</option>
        <option *ngFor="let order of filteredOrders" [value]="order.id">
            {{order.id}}</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

.ts-file

```
export class CustomerFormComponent implements OnInit {

  customerForm: FormGroup;
  selectedCustomer: Customer;
  filteredOrders: Order[];

  customers: Customer[] = [...];
  orders: Order[] = [...];  

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute,
              private fb: FormBuilder) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.customerForm = this.fb.group({
      customer: "",
      order: ""
    });

    let customerId = Number(this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('customerId'));
    this.setFormControlValues(customerId);
  }

  setFormControlValues(customerId: number) {
    if (customerId == 0) {
      this.customerForm.get('customer').setValue("(new customer)");
      this.customerForm.get('order').setValue("(new order)");
    }
    else  {
      this.selectedCustomer = this.customers.find(i => i.id == customerId);
      this.filteredOrders = this.getCustomerOrders(this.selectedCustomer);

      this.customerForm.get('customer').setValue(this.selectedCustomer.name);
      this.customerForm.get('order').setValue(this.filteredOrders[0].orderNumber);
    }
  }

  getCustomerOrders(customer: Customer) : Order[] {
    let orders: Order[] = [];

    for (var id = 0; id < customer.orderIds.length; id++)  {
      let orderId = customer.orderIds[id];
      orders.push(this.orders.find(i => i.id == orderId));
    }

    return orders;
  }

  onCustomerChanged(event: any) {
    this.selectedCustomer = this.customers.find(n => n.name == event.target.value);

    this.setFormControlValues(this.selectedCustomer.id);
  }
}
```

As you can see, in the HTML i now use "[value]" instead of "[ngValue]" and "customer.name" / "order.id" instead of only "customer" / "order".

In the .ts-file I got rid of the "patchValue()" method and brought in the "setValue" method.

Here is the working stackblitz-example:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-conditionaldropdown-gnajge

Answer (score 3):

I think that the problem comes from the object that is selected in the order selector (also in the customers one, in fact).

```
<option [ngValue]="order" *ngFor="let order of filteredOrders">
    {{order.id}}
</option>
```

This means that the whole `order` object will be selected and not only the order id. In this case, if you try to patch the value only with the `order.id`, then it won't work : the selector wait for an `Order` object, not the `order.id`.

I put together a quick stackblitz with a working version of the code you put in the question: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-drop-dowb. The only real difference is that

```
this.customerForm.patchValue({
    orders: this.filteredOrders[0]
});
```

is used instead of

```
this.customerForm.patchValue({
    orders: this.filteredOrders[0].id }
});
```

## Update

So, i've updated the stackblitz.

To keep the `orders` field with the correct values along the `customer`, you'll need to add a `(change)` in the `select` field.

```
<select formControlName="customers" (change)="updateOrders($event)">
    <option [ngValue]="null">(new customer)</option>
    <option [value]="customer.id" *ngFor="let customer of customers" >
        {{customer.name}}
    </option>
</select>
```

Don't forget to pass the customer `id` field as the value instead of the `customer` - Angular does not seem to like it. With the `id` value then, you'll need to add a `updateOrders` function in the `component.ts`.

```
  updateOrders(event) {
    const index = this.customers.findIndex(item => item.id == event.target.value);
    if (index === -1) {
      this.customerForm.controls.orders.setValue(null);
      return;
    }
    this.filteredOrders = this.getCustomersOrders(this.customers[index]);
    this.customerForm.controls.orders.setValue(this.filteredOrders[0]);
  }
```

In the case the `id` is not in the customers list, then you'll only update the `orders` with a `null` value, corresponding to tyour `(new order)`. And if the `id` is in the customers list, then you'll update the `filteredOrders`.

Comment: For me your stackblitz code unfortunately does not work the way I need it. If I switch from Monika to Meghan the order should be 1 again. And if I switch to "new customer" the second drop down should automatically switch to "new order".

Comment: You can always add a `(change)` on the select. But that wasn't mentionned in the initial question, so yeah, the logic for this wasn't implemented in the stackblitz. Update your question and I'll update the stackblitz in the meantime.

Comment: Okay, my bad. Now we wrote our answers at the same time. Both are nearly the same i guess. Thanks for the trouble ;)

Answer (score 2):

If you're using `[ngValue]` you can use `[compareWith]` on your `select` element passing in a comparison function to determine if the value is selected.  Using `[ngValue]` allows for complex objects over `[value]` which is a string.

```html
<form [formGroup]="customerForm">
    <select [compareWith]="compareCustomers" formControlName="customers">
        <option>(new customer)</option>
        <option [ngValue]="customer" *ngFor="let customer of customers">
            {{customer.name}}
        </option>
    </select>
    <select [compareWith]="compareOrders" formControlName="orders">
        <option>(new order)</option>
        <option [ngValue]="order" *ngFor="let order of filteredOrders">
            {{order.id}}
        </option>
    </select>
</form>
```

```js
export class SomeComponent {
  public compareCustomer(a: Customer, b: Customer): boolean {
    return a.id === b.id;
  }

  public compareOrders(a: Order, b: Order): boolean {
    return a.id === b.id;
  }
}
```